# Export a range as a PDF in Google Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script

I've searched all over for some lines of code that would accomplish what I want, but I'm too unfamiliar with how google apps script works. I've only ever coded in Microsoft excel and although I'm not completely lost, I'm still pretty lost.

I am looking for code that would select a range, then "Download as.." the selection to PDF, fit width, portrait, no grid. Ideally this PDF could be sent to a specific folder on my desktop, but I don't know if the apps script supports that.

I've found the methods needed (I think) to establish the width, portrait, no grid. All the other searches I've done convert the entire sheet to a PDF and email it which isn't what I want to do and I couldn't find what parts of those sample codes to delete because it looks like PDFs are recognized as web addresses. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *is* possible to export a range from your Google Sheet without hiding sheet tabs, rows and columns, or creating a temporary new spreadsheet.

```
function exportRangeToPDf(range) {
  var blob,exportUrl,options,pdfFile,response,sheetTabNameToGet,sheetTabId,ss,ssID,url_base;

  range = range ? range : "C4:D4";//Set the default to whatever you want

  sheetTabNameToGet = "Sheet1";//Replace the name with the sheet tab name for your situation
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//This assumes that the Apps Script project is bound to a G-Sheet
  ssID = ss.getId();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabNameToGet);
  sheetTabId = sh.getSheetId();
  url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  //Logger.log('url_base: ' + url_base)

  exportUrl = url_base + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +

    '&gid=' + sheetTabId + '&id=' + ssID +
    '&range=' + range + 
    //'&range=NamedRange +
    '&size=A4' +     // paper size
    '&portrait=true' +   // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' +       // fit to width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true' + //hide optional headers and footers
    '&gridlines=false' + // hide gridlines
    '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  //Logger.log('exportUrl: ' + exportUrl)

  options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;//Make sure this is always set

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);

  //Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())

  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    console.log("Error exporting Sheet to PDF!  Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
    return;

  }
  
  blob = response.getBlob();

  blob.setName('AAA_test.pdf')

  pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);//Create the PDF file
  //Logger.log('pdfFile ID: ' +pdfFile.getId())
}
```

There are various strategies that have been used to export part of a Google Sheet to a PDF.

- Create a new spreadsheet file with just the wanted content
- Create a new sheet tab, put the content in the sheet tab and hide any
  other sheet tabs, hide unwanted rows and columns
- Build a download URL with a range setting

  - Use range address
  - Use a named range - &gid=sheetId&range=NamedRange
- Export content to a Google Doc and create a PDF from the Google Doc
- Merge G-Sheet content with a template file, and create the PDF from
  the template file.
- Get a range of content from the Sheet, convert it to HTML and use the
  HTML to create the PDF file

I would use the method of building a download URL with the range included in the download URL.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no direct way to convert a Range to a PDF (blob) in Google Apps Script.  The best you could do is copy the range values to a blank spreadsheet, apply your formatting, then export that sheet.

You could write the PDF to a folder on Google Drive, then use the Drive software on your computer to sync that folder to the one on your desktop accomplish the last part.

I don't have a snippet of code that does this handy, but here are the relevant documentation links:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getAs(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String)

Comment: Thank you very much Cameron, this is going to put me a huge step forward. I'll try and write up some coding with the info you've given me and if I'm successful, I'll post the results. Again, thank you.

Comment: There is a way to export part of one sheet tab to a PDF file.  See new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Google doc or temporary Google sheet as template, grab the values from specific cell or range, create as pdf save it and delete temporary file from the template.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).