# Export a Google sheet range as pdf using Apps script and store the pdf in drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export-to-pdf

need some help and hope you can help me :)

I have a google spreadsheet document and need to do some actions per script:
Sheet: "Sheet1"
Range: "A1:J39"

1. print out with settings (landscape, perfect width)
2. save as PDF document in a folder in a shared google drive (same settings like no 1)
3. send PDF file per mail to adresses which listed in an other sheet

hope you can help me with this problem....

thx

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703960/export-a-range-as-a-pdf-in-google-apps-script) useful.

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far? @Freeces

Answer (score 3):

I'm giving below code I use to send a full sheet as PDF.
You can modify it slightly to

1.Hide unwanted rows and columns
2.Include PDF export options

```
function send_sheet(){
  var today=new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var ltrsht = ss.getSheetByName("Letter");    
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if(sheets[i].getName()!="Letter"){ sheets[i].hideSheet() }
    }
    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId());
    var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(ltrsht.getRange("C16").getValue()+".pdf");
    var folderID = ""; // Folder id to save in a folder
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
    var body = 'Dear ' + ltrsht.getRange("C16").getValue() +',\n\nPL. find your ' + ltrsht.getRange("C11").getValue() +' enclosed.\n\nHRD Megawin Switchgear';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(ltrsht.getRange("E17").getValue(), ltrsht.getRange("C11").getValue() + " from Megawin HRD", body, {attachments: [theBlob]});
    var empsht = ss.getSheetByName("Emp");  
    empsht.showSheet();
    ltrsht.hideSheet();

}
```

First you have to hide all sheets other than the target sheet
Hide unwanted rows and columns
Convert to PDF
Save in folder
Send to email id which is stored some cell

See below how to format the PDF

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3457043?hl=en

Comment: Is there a way to generate that pdf without google drive permissions?