# creating a PDF from a specific range of cells in google sheets and saving it to google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a button on my google sheet, that when I press it, it will automatically export a specific range of cells in my google sheet, to PDF and save it on my google drive, in a specified folder. The PDF can be landscape and needs to fit all cells to one sheet. No formatting of the google sheet/cells is needed, just export exactly what it sees on the sheet to PDF.

the cell range is:A1-T25

can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61219628/export-a-google-sheet-range-as-pdf-using-apps-script-and-store-the-pdf-in-drive

Comment: That is perfect. So as per that example, I only want number 2, which part of the script/code do I want to copy and paste to my script writer? 
Ps somewhat of a newbie to all this script

Comment: Also thank you a ton Cooper :)