# screenshot of Google spreadsheet range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a range of cells in Google spreadsheet every time a value changes in that range and save the screenshot in a URL or in my drive as .jpg, .png or pdf
I was able to find something similar for taking screenshots of charts but wasn't able to modify the script successfully for this case, has anyone done something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this as a reference, modify if needed:

#### Code:

```
function exportPdf(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  // sample dimension to be checked is B2:E5
  var checkDimension = {
    startingRow: 2,
    startingColumn: 2,
    endingRow: 5,
    endingColumn: 5
  };

  // range should be within checkDimension and Sheet1
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == 'Sheet1' && 
    range.getRow() >= checkDimension.startingRow && 
    range.getLastRow() <= checkDimension.endingRow &&
    range.getColumn() >= checkDimension.startingColumn && 
    range.getLastColumn() <= checkDimension.endingColumn) {
      
    var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
    var exportRange = "B2:E5";
    var urlString = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
      '&gid=' + sheetId + '&id=' + spreadsheetId +
      '&range=' + exportRange + 
      '&size=A4' +         // paper size
      '&portrait=true';   // orientation, false for landscape
    // See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands for more url parameters
    var exportUrl = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit.*$/, urlString);

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
      Logger.log("Error exporting Sheet to PDF!  Response Code: " + response.getResponseCode());
      return;
    }

    var blob = response.getBlob();
    var timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    // set name to spreadsheet_sheet_range_timestamp.pdf
    blob.setName(spreadsheet.getName() + '_' + sheet.getSheetName() + '_' + exportRange + '_' + timestamp + '.pdf');

    var folderId = 'enter your folder ID here';
    // Create the PDF file in the specific folder
    DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob); 
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- For more url parameters, see reference below.
- This needs to be an installable trigger, not a simple one.

#### Output:

[image: output]
[image: output2]

#### References:

- [Url parameters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands)
- [Alan Well's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149717/14606045)